# Using subselects and order() and sum() can I get this to display a second order?

Tags: mysql, sql

Alright, so this may be very long but that comes with the length of my struggle.

So I have three different tables:
`Customers`
`Orders`
`Order_items`

`Customers` and `orders` share `customer_id`
`orders` and `order_items` share `order_id`

I need to display the email from customers, the number of orders each customer has as well as the total cost of each order. I have figured out how to get two out of the three the customer email and the total number of orders. I have also gotten it to display the correct sum for an order. The issue I'm running into is I have customers that have more than one order and it will only give me the total sum of both orders or just one order that is the massive select statement that has gotten me to this point. changing the bold part to orders.customer_id gives me the customer total leaving it as is gives me the single order total. when I print I should have 4 lines instead of 2. There should be two of each email with two of the number of orders and the third should be the total of the two different orders.

[image: current output]

```sql
select t1.email_address, t1.number_of_orders, t2.order_total, t2.order_id from
(select customers.customer_id , email_address, count(email_address) as number_of_orders, orders.order_id from customers join orders on customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id 
group by email_address having number_of_orders > 1) t1 join 
(select orders.order_id, (sum((item_price-discount_amount)*quantity)) as order_total from orders 
join order_items on orders.order_id = order_items.order_id group by ***orders.order_id***) t2
on t1.order_id = t2.order_id;
```

Comment: *"I need to display the email from customers, the number of orders each customer has as well as the total cost of each order."* - That's a contradiction. Either you want the total number of orders and the total cost per customer (=one result row per customer), or you want the cost of each order (=one row per order), but then you can't have the total number of orders anymore. What will it be?

Comment: Well the issue is my professor wants both so I am trying to figure out how to make it happen. Unless I maybe misunderstanding his instructions......

Comment: These are his instructions. 6.1 Write a SELECT statement that returns one row for each customer that has orders with these columns:
The email_address column from the Customers table
A count of the number of orders
The total amount for each order (Hint: First, subtract the discount amount from the price. Then, multiply by the quantity.)
Return only those rows where the customer has more than 1 order.
Sort the result set in descending sequence by the sum of the line item amounts.

Comment: How should "both" look like? You can't have both. Either your query is grouped at the customer level, then each group contains everything the customer dd, but then you lose "per-order" resolution, or it is grouped at the order level, then you can see the individual order totals, but you lose "per-customer" overview.

Comment: yes, the instructions are garbage; you can't have the total amount for each order in a column *and* one row per customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emphasis mine

> Write a SELECT statement that returns **one row for each customer** that has orders with these columns:
>
> - The email_address column from the Customers table A
> - count of the number of orders
> - The total amount for each order (Hint: First, subtract the discount amount from the price. Then, multiply by the quantity.)
>
> Return only those rows where the customer has more than 1 order. Sort the result set in descending sequence by the sum of the line item amounts.

So the task calls for "per customer" grouping.

```
select 
  c.email_address,
  count(o.order_id) as number_of_orders,
  sum((i.item_price - i.discount_amount) * i.quantity) orders_total
from
  customers c
  inner join orders o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
  inner join order_items i on i.order_id = o.order_id
group by
  c.email_address
having
  count(o.order_id) > 1
order by
  sum(i.quantity) desc
```

Not sure about the *"sort [...] by the sum of the line item amounts" part, but I assume `sum(i.quantity)` (i.e. how many items each customer has ordered overall) would be what the professor had in mind.

Comment: I figured I was reading too much into what he wanted. Thank you for your help that makes some much more sense looking at it.

Comment: @Luke By the way, there actually are ways to get both individual totals *and* rolling totals into a grouped query, namely `ROLLUP` (see [mySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html), other DB engines support that, too), but unless you were specifically learning about that, I don't think your professor would have expected that solution. You can add that if you want to impress them. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per order, joining the per-order information from t2 to the per-customer information from t1, you need to join t1 and t2 on customer id, not order id.

Though in mysql 8 or mariadb 10.2+, you would likely use window functions to get total orders per customer, not a separate subquery.

Comment: The problem with that is that t2 can't touch any customer information at this point the only thing it can touch is the customer_id through the orders table

Comment: t2 can select orders.customer_id

Answer (score 0):

What you're dealing with here is, you have to sets of results of different cardinality, and you want to join them. That is, some results pertain to the user (e-mail, number of orders, grand total) and other results pertain to the order (order id, order total), and there's a relationship of one-to-many between customer and orders. We must calculate each result separately, then join them.

We want to calculate the total for one order, then sum those totals for a grand total for the customer.

The order total involves an "intelligence" for calculating the discount, so it would be bad to have to write it twice. What we're gonna do is a common table expression ([CTE](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/)) so we write it only once, then can use it again.

```
;with order_summary
as
(
    select 
        orders.customer_id,
        orders.order_id, 
        sum((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity) as order_total 
    from orders 
    join order_items on orders.order_id = order_items.order_id 
    group by orders.customer_id, orders.order_id
),
customer_summary 
as (
    select
        customers.customer_id, 
        customers.email_address, 
        count(order_summary.order_id) as number_of_orders,
        sum(order_summary.order_total) as order_total
    from customers 
    join order_summary on customers.customer_id = order_summary.customer_id 
    group by customers.customer_id, customers.email_address
)
select
    customer_summary.email_address, 
    customer_summary.number_of_orders, 
    customer_summary.order_total, 
    order_summary.order_id 
from customer_summary
join order_summary or order_summary.customer_id = customer_summary.customer_id; 
order by customer_summary.email_address, order_summary.order_id
```

There may be the occasional typo because I don't have your environment to check it, but in that case it should be easy to adjust it now.